# Best way to insert 50K records into big table (app. 350 columns) in postgresql

Tags: c#, postgresql, bulkinsert

Using `C#` I'm trying to insert from csv file (~ 55000 records) to a `postgresql table` with 350 columns. I'm just building the `insert statement` from header and record which are comma separated.
Like this:

```
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?);
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?);
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?);
INSERT INTO public.table(field1,fields2,field3, ..... ,field350) VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,.......,?);
....etc
```

I tried using `batch`, like gathering 1000 statements and execute them in a `transaction`, but this takes for 1000 records up to ~3 sec.

I tried to follow the example from `Microsoft` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/local-transactions) in which I call `ExecuteNonQuery()` on each line but I `commit` the `transaction` after 1000 records and begin a new `transcation` and this is taking up to ~3 sec per 1000 records as well. Something like this:

```
foreach (var line in ReadCsvFileToList(dataFile))
{
    try
    {
        if (firstLine)
        {
            header = line;
            firstLine = false;
            continue;
        }
        else
        {
            var formattedLine = line.Replace("\"\"", "NULL").Replace("'", "''").Replace("\"", "'");
            var commandText = $"INSERT INTO public.table({header.Replace('/', '_')}) VALUES ({formattedLine})";
            command.CommandText = commandText;
            await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
            round++;
        }

        if (round == 1000) // batch size
        {
            await transaction.CommitAsync();
            Console.WriteLine("batch commited to DB at: " + DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyy hh:mm:ss"));
            round = 0;
            transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        await connection.CloseAsync();
        await connection.DisposeAsync();
        await transaction?.RollbackAsync();
        throw;
    }
}
```

An idea on how to optimize this more?

Comment: You seem to try to approach this without the [native support](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/copy.html).

Comment: May be this will help... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652832/bulk-c-sharp-datatable-to-postgresql-table

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way to read .csv files into a DB, is to do it in the DB Server/DBMS.

C# will never even get close to that performance. And at best you add the load to transfer the whole data over the network once. If you *have* to do it from code, there is usually a proper Bulk Insert way. Apparently for Post Gre that one is called [COPY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/758956/3346583).

If that is not a option either, at least make a explicit DB-transaction. Doing Inserts in a loop will have the DB open and commit a Transaction *every single* INSERT. Instead using a explicit transaction around this can improove performance at least somewhat.

Comment: am i not using the explicit transaction? any code example?

Comment: @alaa_sayegh The first option is to not do it in code at all. | The second best, is to use COPY. Wiktor linked the documentation for it. | So there are no more code examples we could give.