# How to improve bulk inserts to Postgres DB

Tags: c#, postgresql, bulkinsert, postgresql-performance

I currently have a service in C# that uses dapper to call a stored procedure that does 2 things: if the customer exists, it grabs the customer `GUID` and adds it to the `CustomerInformations` table; if the customer doesn't exist, then it inserts the customer and then returns the `GUID` and adds it to the `CustomerInformations` table.

Previously, inserts were taking around 1.75 million records an hour. Now it can barely get 200,000 records an hour. There's around 75 million records in my `CustomerInformations` table and I am looking to fixing the bottleneck.

For each Customer property, it's iteratively calling a stored procedure. Each stored procedure call could have 2 inserts into the database. First, adding the customer into the `Customers` table and then adding the property into the `CustomerInformations` table. I understand that this may not be the most ideal way to store the data but it's not something I can change.

C# service

```
foreach (var info request.Data)
{
    string sql = "add_one_by_customer";
    object parameters = new
    {
        p_customer_first_name = info.FirstName,
        p_customer_last_name = info.LastName,
        p_customer_property_name = info.PropertyName,
        p_customer_property_value = info.PropertyValue
    };

    try
    {
        await db.ExecuteAsync(sql, parameters, transaction: transaction, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        throw new Exception($"Failed to insert");
    }
}
```

Postgres stored procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE add_one_by_customer(
    p_customer_first_name  VARCHAR,
    p_customer_last_name  VARCHAR,
    p_customer_property_name  VARCHAR,
    p_customer_property_value  VARCHAR,
    )
    LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $procedure$
DECLARE p_customer_id uuid;
        p_current_item_value varchar;   
begin   
    SELECT INTO p_customer_id,
                customer_id
    FROM customers
    WHERE customer_first_name = p_customer_first_name AND
          customer_last_name = p_customer_last_name
    limit 1;
                           
    
    IF (p_customer_id IS NULL) THEN  
        begin               
            INSERT INTO customers(customer_first_name, customer_last_name)
            VALUES (p_customer_first_name, p_customer_last_name) RETURNING  customer_id into p_customer_id;
            EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
            p_customer_id  = (SELECT custmomer_id 
                              FROM  customers
                              WHERE customer_first_name = p_customer_first_name AND
                                    customer_last_name = p_customer_last_name
        END;
    end if;    
   
    p_current_item_value := (select property_value
                             from customer_informations
                             where customer_id = p_customer_id AND
                                   customer_property_name = p_customer_property_name);
  

   
    if (p_current_item_value is NULL) THEN
        INSERT INTO customer_informations(customer_id, customer_property_name, customer_property_value)
        VALUES (p_customer_id, p_customer_property_name, p_customer_property_value);
    elseif (p_current_item_value is not null AND p_current_item_value != p_item_value) then
        UPDATE customer_informations 
        SET customer_property_value = p_current_item_value
        WHERE  customer_id = p_customer_id ;        
    end if;
end; $procedure$;
```

Currently my `CustomerInformations` table has a unique constraint on `Customer_Id, Customer_property_name`.

Things I've tried to enhance:

- Parallelize in the service (which is why you see the unique violation exception line in the stored procedure) this does speed it up but not enough.
- I am considering dropping the unique constraint and the index but I am not sure how easy it'll be to clean up duplicates (other individuals interact with the database)

Any tips or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Customer_information unique constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT ux_customer_informations UNIQUE (customer_id, customer_property_name)
```

Customers unique constraint:

```
CONSTRAINT ux_customers UNIQUE (customer_firstname, customer_lastname)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bulk C# datatable to postgresql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652832/bulk-c-sharp-datatable-to-postgresql-table)

Comment: You probably want to use a bulk insert path, eg `BeginBinaryImport`

Comment: Not quite https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652832/bulk-c-sharp-datatable-to-postgresql-table because I need the customer_id generated

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for the tables and indexes involved? And do you have a (unique) index on the combination of customer_first_name and customer_last_name?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html "Table columns not specified in the COPY FROM column list will receive their default values." I admit you can't get the `customer_id` returned from it, but you could requery that if necessary.

Comment: @FrankHeikens, yes I have a unique index for Customers table on first and last name as well.  Updated above to show

Comment: @Charlieface I can't insert the data if I don't have customer_id as it's a nonnull field.

Comment: If it's a serial/identity column then it should generate automatically. But if you want anything complex, `copy` into a staging table, then do a joined `update` or `insert`.

Comment: Could you clarify what has changed between your previously 1.75m / h and current 200k/h inserts? Is it just the database size that has grown?

Comment: @ste-fu, only change is database size.

Comment: Did you check the performance of all individual queries? If so, could you share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings)` for these queries? And the complete DDL for all tables and indexes involved.

Comment: The procedure `add_one_by_customer()` has a couple of syntax errors. Please show the actual working procedure in use. Show exact table definitions (`CREATE TABLE` statements) and your version of Postgres. Consider instructions for [postgresql-performance](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) questions.

Comment: Are the unique constraint indexes the only indexes which exist on those tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current procedure is **hugely inefficient**.  See:

- [Elegant way of handling PostgreSQL exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28436918/elegant-way-of-handling-postgresql-exceptions/28443028#28443028)

**Avoid** a nested code block with error handling, that's very expensive. Can be done properly with the "SELECT or INSERT" technique I use below. See:

- [Is SELECT or INSERT in a function prone to race conditions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15939902/is-select-or-insert-in-a-function-prone-to-race-conditions/15950324#15950324)

The second part is an [UPSERT](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT) in disguise. Also much cheaper now:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE dd_one_by_customer(
      p_customer_first_name      text
    , p_customer_last_name       text
    , p_customer_property_name   text
    , p_customer_property_value  text
      )
  LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
$proc$
DECLARE
   p_customer_id uuid;
   p_current_item_value text;
BEGIN
   LOOP
      SELECT customer_id
      FROM   customers
      WHERE  customer_first_name = p_customer_first_name
      AND    customer_last_name = p_customer_last_name
      INTO   p_customer_id;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
      
      INSERT INTO customers
             (  customer_first_name,   customer_last_name)
      VALUES (p_customer_first_name, p_customer_last_name)
      ON     CONFLICT (customer_first_name, customer_last_name) DO NOTHING
      RETURNING customer_id
      INTO   p_customer_id;

      EXIT WHEN FOUND;
   END LOOP;

   INSERT INTO customer_informations
          (  customer_id,   customer_property_name,   customer_property_value)
   VALUES (p_customer_id, p_customer_property_name, p_customer_property_value)
   ON     CONFLICT (customer_id, customer_property_name) DO UPDATE
   SET    customer_property_value = EXCLUDED.customer_property_value
   WHERE  customer_property_value IS DISTINCT FROM p_current_item_value;
END
$proc$;
```

This requires a `UNIQUE` constraint on each of the two tables - exactly the ones you declared (`ux_customer_informations` & `ux_customers`).

If neither `customer_property_value` nor `p_current_item_value` can be `null`, simplify the final `WHERE` clause to:

```
...
WHERE  customer_property_value <> p_current_item_value;
```

Comment: There were a couple of syntax error and conflicting variable names. (Probably the result of sloppy c/p & obfuscation.) I hope I could see through the fog properly.

Comment: The OP commented that this improved performance for them dramatically. But some admin found it reasonable to remove the comment. Seems like dumb vandalism to me.