# Postgres SQL bulk insert directly from datatable in C#

Tags: c#, postgresql, bulkinsert

'Postgre's SQL bulk data insert directly from datatable in C#, like SQL Server's `SqlBulkCopy`. Is there any way we can directly copy datatable to Postgres database table, without an insert query? I need this code in C#.

like ms sql bulk copy or directly import datatable to postgres sql.
kindly provide solution with working example.

I tried insert statement one by one, but it takes a lot of time. I have millions of records to import, so I need performance and optimization.

Kindly provide a better solution for this

Comment: you can try this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/758956/11094058 or You may refer this link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652832/bulk-c-sharp-datatable-to-postgresql-table